# OpenGL ES presentRenderBuffer duration depends on frameInterval value

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I'm using CADisplayLink to fire the "update" event for a very simple OpenGL ES animation on iOS. The animation has around 10 textured quads. I tried to run this at 60 FPS and I saw some glitches. When changing this to 30 FPS the animation runs smoother. After profiling this I saw that the most of the time is spent in presentRenderBuffer.

These are the results:

```
m_displayLink.frameInterval = 2;

[379406923.204] Update time 0.000358
[379406923.206] Render time 0.001402
[379406923.207] Present time 0.001136
[379406923.238] Update time 0.000370
[379406923.239] Render time 0.001393
[379406923.241] Present time 0.001148
[379406923.271] Update time 0.000368
[379406923.273] Render time 0.001377
[379406923.274] Present time 0.001226
[379406923.305] Update time 0.000380
[379406923.307] Render time 0.001390
[379406923.308] Present time 0.001183
[379406923.338] Update time 0.000375
[379406923.339] Render time 0.001376
[379406923.341] Present time 0.001178
[379406923.372] Update time 0.000981
[379406923.375] Render time 0.001418
[379406923.379] Present time 0.004452
```

From the results from `m_displayLink.frameInterval = 2` profiling I can see that the total frame time is more than enough to achieve 60 FPS, but when changing `m_displayLink.frameInterval` value to `1` the results are unexpected:

```
m_displayLink.frameInterval = 1;  

[379407317.151] Update time 0.000204 
[379407317.152] Render time 0.000827 
[379407317.172] Present time 0.019173 
[379407317.172] Update time 0.000231 
[379407317.173] Render time 0.000856 
[379407317.201] Present time 0.027540 
[379407317.202] Update time 0.000204 
[379407317.202] Render time 0.000834 
[379407317.218] Present time 0.015187 
[379407317.218] Update time 0.000192 
[379407317.219] Render time 0.000803 
[379407317.251] Present time 0.031392 
[379407317.252] Update time 0.000215 
[379407317.253] Render time 0.000858 
[379407317.267] Present time 0.014433 
[379407317.268] Update time 0.000196 
[379407317.269] Render time 0.001248 
[379407317.301] Present time 0.031312
```

As you can see the present time it several times bigger when using

```
m_displayLink.frameInterval = 1;
```

Please note that last command from `Render()` is `glFinish()`

Do you have any idea why there is this unexpected behaviour? Is it possible to achieve 60 FPS(from the first profiling I have around 500FPS!)?

Comment: Due to the deferred nature of the iOS GPUs, CPU-based profiling is all but useless. You're going to see `-presentRenderBuffer:` be overrepresented in those traces simply because that's the point where your application will block and wait for buffered OpenGL ES commands to be executed. Instead, look at the OpenGL ES Driver instrument and see if you're hitting a bottleneck in the tiler or renderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem (pure luck!)  by moving OpenGL initialization from `view initWithFrame`. I know this sounds very awkward, but this reduced my GPU usage from 96% to 6%. Now the simple application runs very smooth at 60 FPS with 2% CPU and 6% GPU usage(as it should be!).

Comment: That's crazy bizarre!  I don't understand why the location of your GL init would change things this significantly...